# What bracha should be made on a smoothie with oats?

Tags: blessing, dagan-five-grains

I know that typically on a smoothie one makes a shehakol, as in most beverages, however since oats are one of the 5 species of grain that are considered primary, and therefore in most cases are considered the ikar, I’m not sure if I should make a mezonos. What if the oats were very well blended? What if I didn’t blend them well and there are “big” chunks of oats? What if I didn’t even blend them and just mixed the with the smoothie (meaning the oats are complete, not in pieces)? What if they’re not even mixed and I just place a few of them on the top whether for aesthetic purposes or for nutrition or taste? I’m not sure if any of these situations would make difference.

Thank you :)

Comment: I believe raw oats are ha'adamah since it's not they're not in a "bread" state.

Comment: @Yehuda even partially processed oats, since they aren't thoroughbread.

Comment: Beer that is made out of barley is still shehakol since it is a drink. I would assume oat smoothie that is blended down to a liquid is the same, like oat milk. In a situation that the oats are made the normal way to eat and therefore have Mezonos status, mixing them in would go into the guidelines of Ikar and Taful, which in this case would probably mean 2 brachos. See the link for a very handy chart on the topic.                          https://www.torahdesigns.com/halachos-of-ikar-vtofel-chart/